# how to check access token validity in django oauth toolkit?

Tags: django, oauth, access-token, django-authentication

I am using `Django-oauth-toolkit` for social authentication. How to check if access token is expired so that I can send the request for a new access token by sending refresh token.

Comment: One way is to send access token to get a protected resource and if response is 401 unauthorized then access token is expired and need to be refreshed